# Bind a list to a grid panel

Tags: c#, wpf

Can I bind a list to a wpf grid?  Each object in the list would have a row and column property to be bound as well.

Note: I am not wanting to use a DataGrid.

Comment: So what do you want to use "Grid"

Comment: Can I ask why you wouldn't want to use a `DataGrid`?

Comment: @Vaccano, you cannot bind to `Grid` directly but you can bind to `ItemsControl`, change `ItemsPanel` to `Grid` and in `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle` bind `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row`

Comment: @dkozl - that sounds just as good.  I will try it out.  Could you post as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot bind to `Grid` directly. What you can do however is use `ItemsControl`, change `ItemsPanel` to `Grid` and in `ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle` bind `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` like below:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <Grid>
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <ColumnDefinition/>
                   <ColumnDefinition/>
                   <ColumnDefinition/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <RowDefinition/>
                   <RowDefinition/>
                   <RowDefinition/>
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           </Grid>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style>
           <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Path=Row}"/>
           <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Path=Col}"/>
       </Style>
   </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```